# Identifying whether a website uses CMS and which

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system

You can do this by looking at only the source code? In my specific case, I wonder if this site a CMS.

http://www.designbridge.com/

Comment: yes, i suppose they are most likely using a CMS – like most pages nowadays do – but it is not always easy to find out which one. And in this case simply looking at the source code didn't help me to draw any conclusion.

You could however try using one of these services:

http://www.onlinewebtool.com/cmsdetector.php

or 

http://www.builtwith.com/

or this firefox extension:

http://www.wappalyzer.com/

but i doubt that it will lead you anywhere in this case.

Why not ask them? …might be worth a try…:)

And may I ask, what your intention actually is?

Answer (score 1):

if you use Firefox u can install **wappalyzer** plugin. 
There're also a lot of online services which detect CMS and used technologies: [builtwith](http://builtwith.com/), [w3techs](http://w3techs.com/sites), etc. The last one says that the given site was built with Umbraco CMS v.4.7

Answer (score 0):

It uses Umbraco 4.7 (ASP.NET framework)

You can look at source code, but in this case I found it in the http response headers.

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Umbraco-Version: 4.7
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Besides checking source and headers manually, you can also use an online tool. A google search for "CMS detector" gives me:

- http://guess.scritch.org/
- http://onlinewebtool.com/cmsdetector.php

Comment: http response headers could easily been manupulated, but it is highly unlikely.

Comment: Thanks Alex. 
You can identify any CMS by http response headers?

Comment: Not always, but some CMSes send custom headers you can use to identify them.

Answer (score -1):

This site seems to use ASP.NET technology from the following piece of source code :

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>
```

But I do no know, if it uses a prewritten ASP.NET CMS or uses some ASP.NET framework or just plain ASP.NET.

If you know what you are looking for, you may use certain fingerprints of CMS's to identify which is which. But it is possible to fake some site to seems as one CMS and infact it is plain or another CMS. There is no certain way to answer this, only you can guess cleverly.